# Why is initializing this way in C giving multiple definition error?

Tags: c

Below are two files which I will use as my example. If I define an array of structures in file1.h and have file2.c include file1.h I would get a multiple definition error. Why is that? If I just have struct thread tasks[32] I don't get this error.

file1.h

```
...
...
struct thread tasks[32] = {0}; // thread is structure defined above
...
...
```

file2.c

```
#include file1.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are including the header file in more than one source file. The `#include` directive literally includes the contents of the header file into the source file, which means that all code in the header file will also be in the source file. This means that if two or more source file includes the same header file then the code in the header file will be duplicated.

Comment: And defining initialized variables in header files is always a very bad habit. You should only declare them in header files (and define them in one compilation unit).

Answer (score 2):

The `= {0}` turns the line from a *declaration* into a *definition*.  You can have as many (compatible) declarations of a file-scope variable as you like, but at most one definition; by including the header in multiple source files you are causing multiple definitions to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent problems from multiple includes by wrapping the contents of your header files in #ifndef like this

```
/* file1.h */
#ifndef INCLUDE_FILE1
#define INCLUDE_FILE1

/* contents here */

#endif
```

Comment: This will only protect the header file to be included twice in the same source file, it will not protect it from being included in multiple source files.